# Process and display lidar data

Tags: opencv, ros, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am a newbie to lidar processing. I am interested in the depth/range value of the lidar data. I would like to extract these values and display just like the image data as shown in the code. What would be the best way to do it? I have only shown the relevant part of the code

```
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>

static const std::string OPENCV_WINDOW = "Image window";

using namespace sensor_msgs;
using namespace message_filters;

void callback(const ImageConstPtr& image1, const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& pc1)
 {
   cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
   try
   {
     cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(image1, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);
   }
   catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
   {
     ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
     return;
   }

    // Update GUI Window
    cv::imshow(OPENCV_WINDOW, cv_ptr->image);
    cv::waitKey(3);
```

Comment: you can either render the raw lidar map as a depth map or you can render the 3d points either after tesselation (polygon mesh) or with point-wise-rendering

Comment: pcl::PCLPointCloud2 pcl_pc2;
   pcl_conversions::toPCL(*input,pcl_pc2);
   pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr temp_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
   pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(pcl_pc2,*temp_cloud);
   pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer ("Simple Cloud Viewer");
   viewer.showCloud(temp_cloud);
   while (!viewer.wasStopped ())
   {
 
   }

Comment: @Micka I am able to display the point cloud using this script but not able to update it. I tried "viewer->spin()", but it is not working